# "Unable to resolve service for type" error when injecting IHostedService in another IHostedService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am trying to inject an instance of `IHostedService` into another `IHostedService` but I always get the above error when `Run()` is called in my `Program.cs`.

Basically, I have two services:

```
public class CacheService : HostedService
{
    public CacheService()
    {

    }

    /...
}
public class ClientService : HostedService
{
    private CacheService _cacheService;

    public ClientService(CacheService cacheService)
    {
        _cacheService = cacheService;
    }

    /...
}
```

`HostedService` implements `IHostedService`:

```
public abstract class HostedService : IHostedService
{
    // Example untested base class code kindly provided by David Fowler: https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/a7dd5064d9dcf35b6eae1a7953d615e3

    private Task _executingTask;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Create a linked token so we can trigger cancellation outside of this token's cancellation
        _cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);

        // Store the task we're executing
        _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_cts.Token);

        // If the task is completed then return it, otherwise it's running
        return _executingTask.IsCompleted ? _executingTask : Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Stop called without start
        if (_executingTask == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Signal cancellation to the executing method
        _cts.Cancel();

        // Wait until the task completes or the stop token triggers
        await Task.WhenAny(_executingTask, Task.Delay(-1, cancellationToken));

        // Throw if cancellation triggered
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }

    // Derived classes should override this and execute a long running method until 
    // cancellation is requested
    protected abstract Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

This is how I inject these services in my Startup.cs class:

```
private void AddRequiredServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, CacheService>();
    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, ClientService>();
}
```

However, every time I run the application, I get an error that `CacheService` can't be resolved for service `ClientService`. Am I doing something wrong here or is this not supported?

EDIT: [Here](https://github.com/LeonidasFettikus/DIExample/tree/master/WebApplication2) is a repository that you can clone which reproduces my issue.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are injecting the CacheService/ClientService in a constructor please?

Comment: What do you mean? The first code block illustrates how I accept CacheService as constructor parameter in ClientService.

Comment: Sorry. I missed that. It must be Friday :-)

Answer (score 2):

As you are not injecting the `IHostedService` interface in your classes you should register the `ClientService` and `CacheService` directly to the service collection, instead of using the interface e.g.

```
private void AddRequiredServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<CacheService>();
    services.AddSingleton<ClientService>();
}
```

The Dependency Injector (DI) will be able to resolve the correct service and inject it into your constructor.

When you add a service with an interface, the DI will look for references to the interface in constructors and not the class, which is why it fails in your example to inject the correct instance.

Comment: If I do it like you said, I don't get an error. However, my services don't seem to be instantiated. I set breakpoints in the constructor and they are never hit when running the application.

Comment: So far, the only way I got this to work is to remove the HostedService base class from cache service. This isn't really viable though. :(

Comment: Seems a bit odd to me. Maybe you should file an issue on the [github page](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues)

Comment: I already posted the same question on the ASP.Net Core project on GitHub and they told me to post a question here instead or file a bug report on the ASP.Net project. However, I don't even think the latter would make sense since I believe they changed a lot with .Net Core DI.

Answer (score 0):

@Simply Ged, your solution worked for me but it does not make sense to me. I am trying to achieve the same thing in my current project and were struggling since yesterday. Glad I found your post.

This post will help.

[Injecting SimpleInjector components into IHostedService with ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394666/injecting-simpleinjector-components-into-ihostedservice-with-asp-net-core-2-0)

Comment: @LeonidasFett,  you are correct, it is not instantiated services. Let me know if you find any solution.