# Why does my HomeController not get instantiated when I register an IHostedService

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0

I've been scratching my head trying to get this to work but nothing I try seems to.

To summarise, I'm trying to:
1) register as a singleton, one of my services which is started by an `IHostedService` wrapper 
2) have my HomeController instantiated on app startup with the above service injected

I started with the following, and attempted various versions of it to no avail:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddSingleton<IRunnerA, RunnerA>();
    services.AddSingleton<IRunnable>
    (
        services => services.GetRequiredService<IRunnerA>()
        // services => services.GetService<IRunnerA>() does not work either
    );

    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, RunnableWrapper>(); // the IHostedService wrapper
}
```

While `RunnableWrapper` does kick off on app startup (i.e., its `StartAsync` is invoked), my `HomeController` below never gets instantiated:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private IRunnerA _runnerA;

    public HomeController
    (
        ILogger<HomeController> logger,
        IRunnerA runnerA
    )
    {
        // Never reaches here while debugging, given the above services config.
    }
```

**Question:** Why isn't my `HomeController` getting instantiated?

===

**Further info:**
Among the many things I attempted, I also tried what was suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52398431, but I still get the same behaviour.

**Observations:**

1. Weirdly enough, if I remove the line `services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, RunnableWrapper>();`, my `HomeController` does get instantiated on app startup.
2. If I return from my `RunnableWrapper`'s `public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)` method without performing a long running operation inside it (which I thought was the whole point of a background service), my `HomeController` does get instantiated.

Comment: Use AddHostedService.

Comment: @Nkosi DIdn't work unfortunately. Same behaviour.

Comment: Then the issue is related to whatever the hosted service is doing.

Comment: @Nkosi While not the whole story, that suggestion of yours got me thinking, and I figured it out. Will submit an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem lies with starting a long running task in the `IHostedService` when it's registered inside `ConfigureServices` within `Startup`.
For whatever reason, it appears to block `ApplicationStarted`.

As per this section, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#ihostedservice-interface, I removed the line `services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, RunnableWrapper>();`, and updated `CreateHostBuilder` to the following:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<RunnableWrapper>();
    });
```

Now things work as expected.

I'm not sure why `StartAsync` in the `IHostedService` is called before application start by default; if it has a long running task then it just seems to block.