# How to get base server address in an IHostedService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

In my ASP.NET Core web app I have an `IHostedService` object which performs some tasks periodically by using a timer.

Those tasks should retrieve the base server URL so I am trying this to do it:

Implemented `StartAsync` method:

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(
        () =>
        {
            _baseUrl = GetBaseUrl();
        });

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Where `GetBaseUrl()` method is:

```
private string GetBaseUrl()
{
    ICollection<string>? addresses = _server.Features.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>()?.Addresses ?? null;
    if (addresses != null && addresses.Count > 0)
    {
        return addresses.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

After that code, the URL gotten by `Addresses` property is only one and strangely, it has a Kestrel port, My site is running under IISEXPRESS in port 44375.

How can I do it?

Of course, `_server` is a `IServer` and `_hostApplicationLifetime` is a `IHostApplicationLifetime` passed using DI into the hested service.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to inject a reference to a specific IHostedService implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51254053/how-to-inject-a-reference-to-a-specific-ihostedservice-implementation)